# Filter Datagridview based on other Datagridview table value in VB

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Is something like this possible?  I have 2 datagridview table connected to 2 different sqladapters and datasets, both have values in totalminutes. I'm trying to filter the row from my 2nd datagrid that has the same unknown value as the 1st datagrid cell value.

```
Dim com1r2 As String = "SELECT * from BITD WHERE time >= '% $DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(2).Value $%' "
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VeRN.jpg

Comment: Do you have a variable to join the dataset tables? It would be helpful if you could provide table examples.

Comment: No i don't have  a variable to join, the number of rows are actually different. I add the link for my printscreen, not enough rep :(. You can see the red circles I made. I want to filter other rows in the table below, that have lesser totalminutes value than the upper table (DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(2).Value)

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Please clarify your question again. do you want to perform: If value from column wkt_buk < Minutes Arrived. But what is the bound value 889.552... or 952.85... how do you want to choose which value is the relevant? Or do you want to check: table(1).row(1) < table(2).row(1)... what to do with the overhanging rows then (you said the are unequal).

Comment: Yes, i want to try (<=) ..If value from column wkt_buk < Minutes Arrived.. (889.552... or 952.85) those are current time that were converted to totalminutes and substract etc. The relevant rows are the one who wkt_buk < Minutes Arrived from latest row, that is row number 1.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response. I finally figured it out. This worked for my requirement. Cheers.

```
  Dim tes As Single = DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(2).Value - 600
  Dim com1r2 As String
  com1r2 = "Select * from BITD WHERE nama_asal = 'Bandara Husein' AND tipe_tujuan = 'o' AND wkt_buk <= " & Val(tes) & " ORDER BY skr_lok DESC, wkt_jln ASC "
  Dim sqldataadapter1r2 As New SqlDataAdapter(com1r2, con)
  sqldataadapter1r2.Fill(DataSet21, "bitd")
  DataGridView1r2.DataSource = DataSet21.Tables(0)
```